# How to convert a string representation of a type to the type itself in C++?

Tags: c++, decltype

I'm new to C++, and there is a need to convert a string representation of a type to the type itself, like this:

`"int"` to `int`
`"float"` to `float`
etc...

But, it seems to be very hard to achieve it.  For example, in pseudo code:

```cpp
//how to implement this function or something like this...
auto gettype(string typestr);

//usage
string types[4] = {"int", "double", "float", "string", ...};
gettype(type[0]) val; //then the type of val is int
```

Comment: How do you intend to initialize `val` if you were to hypothetically get this working? _"there is a need to convert a string representation of a type to the type itself"_ -- I find this unlikely. What is the [_actual problem_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Why do you need this?  What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: A function can only have a single return type. Just because it's declared `auto` doesn't mean it can change depending on input. I think you have an [xy-problem](https://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @Patrick Roberts Assume that its value is converted from a string, too

Comment: Are you trying to write an interpreter? Something like [ChaiScript](https://chaiscript.com/)?

Comment: doing this is a little trickier than you might expect. Why do you need it? Quite likely there are easier solutions for your original problem

Answer (score 4):

There is no way that you can have `gettype(type[0]) val;` be a declaration.

The closest I can think of would be

```
constexpr char int_t[] = "int";
constexpr char double_t[] = "double";
constexpr char float_t[] = "float";
constexpr char string_t[] = "string";

constexpr const char * types[] = { int_t, double_t, float_t, string_t };

template <const char *> struct gettype;

template<> struct gettype<int_t> { using type = int; };
template<> struct gettype<double_t> { using type = double; };
template<> struct gettype<float_t> { using type = float; };
template<> struct gettype<string_t> { using type = std::string; };

template <const char * name> using gettype_t = typename gettype<name>::type;
```

This requires the parameter be a compile time constant, but you can have

```
gettype_t<type[0]> val;
```

so long as `type` is [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) and has a `constexpr operator[]`.

Comment: `std::variant<tag<int>, tag<double>, tag<float>, tag<std::string>>` might be a runtime solution.

Comment: @Jarod42 how does that help declare `val`?

Comment: Then you might `std::visit` and call a template method which create type from the tag AND do the job.